# Pandas Modify DataFrames in Loop Part 2

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

Given the following data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
k=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1],'B':[3,4]})
e=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1],'B':[6,7]})
k
    A   B
0   1   3
1   1   4

e
    A   B
0   1   6
1   1   7
```

I'd like to apply a group-by sum in a loop, but doing so does not seem to modify the data frames.

Here's what I've tried:

```
for d in dfsout:
    d=d.groupby(d.columns[0]).apply(sum)
    print(d)
```

When I print d in the loop, it shows that the correct operation is occurring...

```
   A  B
A      
1  2  7
   A   B
A       
1  2  13
```

...but then when I print data frames k and e, they have not been modified.

```
k
    A   B
0   1   3
1   1   4

e
    A   B
0   1   6
1   1   7
```

**Update**

I also tried using it as a function (works in loop, still does not modify):

```
def moddf(d):
    return d.groupby(d.columns[0]).apply(sum)
for d in dfsout:
    d=moddf(d)
    print(d)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is almost the same with your previous question  , you can using the same method .

Comment: @Wen - I tried using that method but it would not modify the data frames in the way I needed. I did not do it in the same loop, however, as I'm not sure how.

Comment: @DanceParty2 I posted my answer again ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , you can try this

```
import pandas as pd
k=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1],'B':[3,4]})
e=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1],'B':[6,7]})
fields=['k','e']
dfsout=[k,e]
variables = locals()
for d,name in zip(dfsout,fields):
    variables["{0}".format(name)]=d.groupby(d.columns[0]).apply(sum)


k
Out[756]: 
   A  B
A      
1  2  7
e
Out[757]: 
   A   B
A       
1  2  13
```

Comment: What is the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

First, define the function

```
def moddf(d):
    return d.groupby(d.columns[0]).apply(sum)
```

Next, reassign modified data frames like this:

```
k,e=[moddf(x) for x in dfsout]
```

or

```
dfsout2=[moddf(x) for x in dfsout]
```